# Override a mocked consumer body for certain tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following test which works.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import MyLogin from '../../src/components/MyLogin';

const mockContent = {
  data: {
    config: {
      myImage: 'mock_image',
    },
  },
};

jest.mock('../../src/utils/config', () => ({
  Consumer: ({ children }) => children(mockContent),
}));

describe('Component Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  const render = () => mount(
    <MyLogin />
  );

  it('should render the component', () => {
    const renderedModule = render();
    expect(renderedModule).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But I wish to add another test where the values inside the mockContent changes.

I have added a `isValid` key.

Thus tried the following where I am trying to over ride mock only for this test.

But this doesn't work. No errors. No effect from this mock.

If I had added this new key `isValid` at the above mock outside the test, it does have the desired effect. (Can't do that of course cos that would affect my other tests)

Could I get some help with this pls.

```
describe('Component Test', () => {
  // other tests

  it('my new test', () => {

    // attempting to override the above mock. 
    const myNewMockContent = {
        data: {
            config: {
                myImage: 'mock_image_2',
                isValid: true,
            },
        },
    };

    jest.mock('../../src/utils/config', () => ({
        Consumer: ({ children }) => children(myNewMockContent),
    }));

    const renderedModule = render();
    expect(renderedModule).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```